# How to use powershell to reorder a string to obfuscate a hidden message?

Tags: powershell, obfuscation

Just for fun a friend and I are trying to find a creative way to send coded messages to eachother using steganography.I stumbled upon doing something like whats shown below and I have been struggling trying to write a function to automate the process.

```
this is a secret message

can be turned into:

("{2}{1}{0}{3}"-f'ecret m','is a s','this ','essage')
```

splitting the string and using reordering seems to be the way to go.

- So the string needs to be split in random splits between 5-10 characters
  .
- The index of the original positions need to be saved
- the splits need to be swapped around
- and the new indexes sorted as to reorder the message properly

i've just really been struggling
help is appreciated

Comment: If I remember right steganography is about to hide some data inside a bigger amount of other data - not just reordering. ;-)

Comment: correct. the idea is to hide the secret message at the bottom of the binary data of an image. But we dont want the "secret message" to be in plain text hence the obfuscation function.

Comment: why not just use: `[char[]]"this is a secret message" | Sort-Object -Property { Get-Random }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun ....

```
$InputMessage = 'this is a secret message'

$SplittedString = $InputMessage -split '' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1

[array]::Reverse($SplittedString)

foreach ($Character in $SplittedString) {
    if ($Character -notin $CharacterList) {
        [array]$CharacterList += $Character
    }
}

foreach ($Character in ($InputMessage -split '' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1)) {
    $Index = [array]::indexof($CharacterList, $Character)
    $Output += "{$Index}"
}
$Result = "'$Output' -f $(($CharacterList | ForEach-Object {"'$_'"}) -join ',')"

$Result
```

And the output of this would be:

```
'{6}{10}{9}{3}{5}{9}{3}{5}{2}{5}{3}{0}{8}{7}{0}{6}{5}{4}{0}{3}{3}{2}{1}{0}' -f 'e','g','a','s','m',' ','t','r','c','i','h'
```

And the output of this would be:

```
this is a secret message
```

And now if you want to go fancy with it you remove the curly braces and the quotes and the commas and the `-f` and add only the numbers and characters to the data. ;-)

Comment: ok so i got called out a little bit ha 

so hypothetically I have the current base64 string for 'start notepad' 

'cwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAbgBvAHQAZQBwAGEAZAA='

it did not work with your current solution. 

is there a way to break the (message) string into groups of smaller substrings like 10 for example ha and re order them?

Comment: ok so I ran your code line for line and interesting things started to happen. 
1. for some reason it is not adding all of the characters to the character list by the end
2. the group of indexes {-1}{5}{6}{11} get repeated a total of 3 times

not actually sure why that is happening but worked fine with the simple example text

Comment: ahhhh i figured out why, it doesnt add both upper and lower case letters to the array so it reads wrong

Comment: ??? What? ... if you run the code in the same console again and again the variables collect  each run. So you have to reset them! ;-) And since PowerShell is by default case insensitive you will have to find a solution if you have capitals in your secret message. ;-)

Comment: Lol I figured it out. You are appreciated it was annoying but yea it works haha

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for but this might give you something to start with:

```sh
class Encode {
    [string] $EncodedMessage
    [int[]]  $Map
    [int]    $EncodingComplexity = 3

    Encode ([string] $Value) {
        $this.Shuffle($Value)
    }

    Encode ([string] $Value, [int] $Complexity) {
        $this.EncodingComplexity = $Complexity
        $this.Shuffle($Value)
    }

    [void] Shuffle([string] $Value) {
        $set = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?'
        $ref = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new()
        $ran = [random]::new()
        $enc = [char[]]::new($Value.Length * $this.EncodingComplexity)

        for($i = 0; $i -lt $enc.Length; $i++) {
            $enc[$i] = $set[$ran.Next($set.Length)]
        }

        for($i = 0;  $i -lt $Value.Length; $i++) {
            do {
                $x = $ran.Next($enc.Length)
            } until($ref.Add($x))
            $enc[$x] = $Value[$i]
        }

        $this.EncodedMessage = [string]::new($enc)
        $this.Map = $ref
    }
}

class Decode {
    static [string] DecodeMessage ([Encode] $Object) {
        return [Decode]::DecodeMessage($Object.EncodedMessage, $Object.Map, $Object.EncodingComplexity)
    }

    static [string] DecodeMessage ([string] $EncodedMessage, [int[]] $Map) {
        return [Decode]::DecodeMessage($EncodedMessage, $Map, 3)
    }

    static [string] DecodeMessage ([string] $EncodedMessage, [int[]] $Map, [int] $Complexity) {
        $decoded = [char[]]::new($EncodedMessage.Length / $Complexity)
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $decoded.Length; $i++) {
            $decoded[$i] = $EncodedMessage[$Map[$i]]
        }
        return [string]::new($decoded)
    }
}
```

Encoding a message:

```
PS /> $message = 'this is a secret message'
PS /> $encoded = [Encode] $message
PS /> $encoded

EncodingComplexity EncodedMessage                                                           Map
------------------ --------------                                                           ---
                 3 B$h^elu2w#CeeHH^qa siQJ)t}es:.a3 ema=eN(GiIcsO;tst1 .fsg}eSUk7ms4 N>rfe# {49, 2, 41, 27…}
```

For decoding the message you can either use **the object of the type `Encode`** or you can give your friend the **Encoded Message and the Map to decode it ;)**

```
PS /> [Decode]::DecodeMessage($encoded)

this is a secret message

PS /> [Decode]::DecodeMessage('B$h^elu2w#CeeHH^qa siQJ)t}es:.a3 ema=eN(GiIcsO;tst1 .fsg}eSUk7ms4 N>rfe#', $encoded.Map)

this is a secret message
```